# How do I get the login form submitted values in hook_user_login()?

Tags: 8, hooks

Since `hook_user_login()` in Drupal 8 has only 1 arg, how can I get the values submitted in the form? In other words, what is the equivalent of `$edit['input]['element_name']` I would use in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

If you need values from the submitted form, you should use `hook_form_alter()` to add a new form submission handler to the form, and get the submitted values when the form is submitted. `hook_user_login()` has never meant to be used to do anything on form values, but merely to inform modules that a user has been logged in.
Actually, you could not even know which form has been submitted because `hook_user_login()` is invoked from [`user_login_finalize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_finalize/8.2.x), which is called from the following methods:

- [`RegistermForm::save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21RegisterForm.php/function/RegisterForm%3A%3Asave/8.2.x)
  A user registered on the site, which doesn't require users verify their email
- [`UserLoginForm::submitForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Form%21UserLoginForm.php/function/UserLoginForm%3A%3AsubmitForm/8.2.x)
  A user filled the login form with username and password
- [`UserPasswordResetForm::submitForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Form%21UserPasswordResetForm.php/function/UserPasswordResetForm%3A%3AsubmitForm/8.2.x)
  A user reset the account password