# How do i attach a an element to user account?

Tags: users, 8

I have added a custom form element in login form. I need to link this new element to user account on logging in.

I need to add and get entry to the table "users_data" in Drupal 8. 
This can be done by defining a class EmployeeDetails and then fetch the value like this :

```
$employee_details = new EmployeeDetails($account);
$employee_details->setEmployeeNumber($value);
```

My Question is in which file should i define EmployeeDetails class? What should be file name, should i use .inc extension and where in the module should be this file placed?

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked a few days ago? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205951/how-do-i-get-the-login-form-submitted-values-in-hook-user-login

Comment: @Clive not exactly same. That was Q for  category  argument in user_save function and working of user_save in D-8. This is a more generic about attaching a form element to user acccount.

Comment: Is there a reason you think the answer to this is going to be different to what kiamlaluno outlined in the answer to your last question? Currently there isn't enough information for this to stay open, I'm just trying to get more details to make it an answerable question

Comment: I need to port something like this $user->data['xyz'] from d7 to d8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported in [users.data column replaced with user_data API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1852360), the equivalent of using the user.data column, in Drupal 8, is using the [user.data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.services.yml/service/user.data/8.2.x) service.

So, if in Drupal 7 you used `$value = $account->data['mymodule_xyz'];`, in Drupal 8 you will use the following code.

```
$value = \Drupal::service('user.data')->get('mymodule', $account->id(), 'xyz');
```

The code to set its value is the following one.

```
\Drupal::service('user.data')->set('mymodule', $account->id(), 'xyz', $value);
```

As usual, when possible, use dependency injection to get the service, instead of using the `\Drupal` class.